# Can i pass codeship env in docker build

Tags: docker, codeship

Can I pass the code ship env ex.CI_BRANCH to docker build. I'm must be use it to run bulid backpack separate build for staging or production by CI_BRANCH

Comment: You should try it and include any errors in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to utilize the Codeship environment variables during the image build time.

You can however pass along these environment variables during run time with a step command:

`command: /bin/bash -c './script_dependent_on_timestamp.sh $CI_TIMESTAMP'`